# Run sequelize hooks on a specific column

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

There's a hook function I have on my `User` model that generates an API key with the crypto module and hashes it, it's attached to the `beforeCreate` hook. Now I want to create a route that enables a user to generate a fresh/new API key, is there a way to trigger that hook so it generates a new API key on just that field of a particular user and I return that field to the frontend.

```
User.generateKey = function() {
  const apiKey = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");

  this.api_key = crypto
    .createHash("sha256")
    .update(apiKey)
    .digest("hex");

  return apiKey;
};

const setApiKey = user => {
  user.api_key = User.generateKey();
};

User.beforeCreate(setApiKey)
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to use hooks to solve the problem they are not intended to. Just to use `User.update` is not enough?

Comment: @Anatoly just to get you , does it mean i can't generate a new API key for a new user with the above hooks function?
Would i have to create another function that generates an API key, run it then insert into DB ?

Comment: Yes, you can use hooks for that. I'm just saying that you can extract the main code of `API key generation` to a separate function and use it in both places: in this hook while creating users and to update a user by `User.update`.